# Paradox: Creating an uncountable set of natural numbers

Tags: cardinals, natural-numbers

Consider the following (contrived) way of enumerating and counting the natural numbers.

Step 1. 
Enumerate the first numbers 0 and 1. These are all the numbers less than $2^1$. Collect these numbers in a set $A_1=\{0, 1\}.$

Step $k$. 
In step $k$, beginning with $k=2$ after step 1, continue the previous enumeration with the numbers from $2^{k-1}$ up to and excluding $2^k$. Collect all the numbers in a set: $A_k=\{j: j\lt 2^k\}.$  Note that the cardinality (number of members) of $A_k$ is $2^k$.

Note that 
(a) The sets $A_k$ can be viewed as a sequence of sets $(A_k)$ with increasing index $k=1,2,\dots$

(b) The successive cardinalities of $(A_k)$ can be viewed as a sequence of natural numbers $(s_k)$ with increasing index $k=1,2,\dots$; where $s_k=2^k$.

(c) It takes an infinite number of steps to enumerate all the natural numbers. So $k$ must approach infinity.

The final cardinality of the completed set of all natural numbers is then
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k=  \lim_{k\to\infty}2^k;$$
Using cardinal exponentiation, and observing that countable infinity has the cardinal number $\aleph_0$, i.e. $k\to\aleph_0$, the limit appears to become
$$\lim_{k\to\aleph_0}2^k =2^{\aleph_0},$$
which is an uncountable cardinal number.

But we only enumerated all the natural numbers. They are supposed to be countable.

How is this paradox resolved?
There must be at least one logical error somewhere.

---

**Update**: Thanks for all comments and answers. The evaluation of the limit above is not valid.

**Follow-up question**: What is a correct way to perform the computation of the limit stated above:
$$  \lim_{k\to\infty}2^k=?
\lim_{k\to\aleph_0}2^k \ ? $$

First off, is the second form a well-formed expression at all? (I.e. is it valid to apply limits  to cardinals?)

Second, (when) is it valid to transform "$\infty$" to a transfinite number such as $\omega$ (ordinal) or $\aleph_0$ (cardinal)? (My understanding is that "$\infty$" symbolises "[increase] forever, indefinitely" rather than any particular transfinite end value.)

Third, how does one reason towards the correct result, which in this case ought to be
$$ 2^\omega = \omega = \aleph_0 \ ?
$$

$2^k$ originates from cardinality. It is less obvious whether the index variable $k$ should be ordinal or cardinal.

Could one say that the original logical error was in thinking that $k$ is a cardinal when it should have been ordinal in the context of this example?

Comment: Cardinal exponentiation is not continuous, so $\lim_{k\to\aleph_0}2^k=2^{\aleph_0}$ is false.

Comment: Hmm... what's the meaning of "continuous" in this case? Is it that one cannot transition from finite to infinite cardinality like that?

Comment: @AndersH What do $\lim_{k\to\infty} u_k$ and $\lim_{k\to\aleph_0} u_k$ mean to you, given a function $u_\bullet:\Bbb N\to\text{cardinals}$ ?

Comment: @AndersH They mean $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ isn't continuous in the sense that it's not necessarily true that $\lim_{k\to\aleph_0} 2^k = 2^{\lim_{k\to \aleph_0} k}$. Continuity means that you can interchange the function with limits.

Comment: @AndersH As spaceisdarkgreen said, the definition of continuous can be taken to be that $f:A\to B$ is continuous if and only if whenever $\lim a_\lambda=a$ for a **net** $(a_\lambda)$ in $A$, then $\lim f(a_\lambda)=f(a)$. Subsets of the class of ordinals (and therefore subsets of the class of cardinals, which can be taken to be a subclass of the ordinals) have the order topology, which is the topology of convergence you're appealing to when you write $\lim_{k\to \aleph_0}2^k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far. I respect them all but particularly appreciate the way @spaceisdarkgreen clarified it. Why don't you write up an "answer" to this effect, and I will accept it. However, I   do have followup q:s about it; one follows shortly in a separate comment.

Comment: I can appreciate that my evaluation of the limit was invalid. However, I'm confused by all these references to continuity. In this example we have a discrete-valued sequence of a discrete variable. In that context I think, "interchange the function with limits", is somehow about being able to break the function down into convergent components. Isn't "continuity" a higher-order thing which is usually defined for functions in terms of convergence of strategically related sequences. (I'm automatically thinking about real numbers and calculus, of course.)

Comment: [Reply to myself] Ok, so I suppose this was what @jwhite tried to explain, only it was a little hard to take in...

Comment: Limits are a notion from topology. It doesn't concern itself with discrete vs. continuous (although that's the focus of calculus, where most people see limits for the first and only time). 

Continuity of a function $f:X\to Y$ at the point $a\in X$ captures the notion that as the inputs $x$ "get closer to" $a$, $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $f(a)$. Topology is how we formalize "get closer to". 

Letting $X$ denote the set of cardinals not exceeding $\aleph_0$, we have a function $f(k)=2^k$. This function is not continuous at $a=\aleph_0$.

Comment: Continuity at $a=\aleph_0$ is exactly equivalent to asking whether we can exchange the limit and the evaluation at $f$. That is, is it true that $$\lim_{k\to \aleph_0} 2^k=\lim_{k\to \aleph_0} f(k)=f(\lim_{k\to \aleph_0}k)=f(\aleph_0)=2^{\aleph_0}?$$ The answer is no, since, as $k$ grows, $2^k<\aleph_0$, which is not "arbitrarily close" to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity: is $k$ and $2^k$ regarded as getting  "arbitrarily close" to $\omega=\aleph_0$ as $k$ grows without limit?

Comment: @AndersH Yes, in the sense of the order topology on the ordinals (or the cardinals) those sequences both converge to $\omega=\aleph_0$.